# How To Target A Specific Cell With Selenium CSS Selectors

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-ide

I've recently gotten into Selenium and I've found myself unable to find a way to target a specific cell in a table. The Div is TestTable1, table is TestTable1_ct111, the row is TestTable1_ct111__0, and I'm trying to access the second cell. I was wondering the xpath I would have to use to be able to target this said cell.

Comment: Please could you post some actual HTML?

Comment: you need to paste fragment of the HTML. Also decide if the question is about CSS selector, or xpath, or both, because title says one thing, and actual question names the other

Answer (score 0):

Use XPaths.

XPaths support "indexing" for a specific element out of a list of possible elements. For example, given the following table:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Bye</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Bye</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If I wanted to select the "Bye" `td` element in the second `tr` element in this table, I could use the following XPath:

```
//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]
```

The important parts in this XPath are `tr[2]` where I am limiting my search to the second `tr` element out of all the `tr` children contained within `tbody`. The second part is `td[2]` that limits my search to the second `td` element within the second `tr` element already specified.

Note that XPath "indexing" starts at 1, not at 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='TestTable1_ct111']/tbody/tr[0]/td[1]")).getText();
```

Hope it helps!